# Ubuntu 22.10 - Enabling fscrypt for user directory after installation

Tags: encryption, 22.10

Best practices for encrypting files on a Ubuntu computer (e.g. to prevent data loss from stolen laptops that were locked or shut down while being stolen) appear to change from time to time. With ecryptfs for user home directory encryption not being recommended any more nowadays, and full-disk encryption being available as an alternative, it looks like that with Ubuntu 22.10, fscrypt is an [officially supported way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1430120/reinstall-ubuntu-22-04-with-fscrypt-encrypted-home-directory) to encrypt home directories or parts thereof if full-disk encryption is not desired.

**What is a suitable way to enable fscrypt for a user directory *or* selected subdirectories thereof with automatic unlocking on login after the installation of Ubuntu 22.10 or one of its variants?** There is a documentation for [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fscrypt), which appears to be up-to-date, and a [blog entry for Ubuntu 18.10](http://tlbdk.github.io/ubuntu/2018/10/22/fscrypt.html) can be found. However, the former may not apply to Ubuntu well. Since encryption appears to be a topic of active development, the latter (blog entry) may be heavily outdated.